# Contradictory statement about linear nonhomogeneous second-order ordinary differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My lecturer had the following in their lecture:

[image]

Is it not contradictory to say that the equation in question is a linear nonhomogeneous differential equation with **constant** coefficients, and then to say that $p(x), q(x)$, and $g(x)$ are **arbitrary functions** of $x$?

Thank you for any clarification.

Comment: Yes, $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ would have to be constant, but $g(x)$ need not be constant in order to be considered constant coefficient,

Comment: @dannum Thanks for the response. So, just to be sure before I start sending emails, it is indeed a contradictory error?

Comment: It does look like a typo. They probably meant to say "non-constant coefficients".

Comment: if $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are functions of $x$ then the equation has non constant coefficients

Comment: Ok, thanks all.